# How to make modify Sliverappbar so I can see the background image with FlexibleSpaceBar when I scroll up?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How to make modify Sliverappbar so I can see the background image with FlexibleSpaceBar when I scroll up?

```
SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 200.0,
          floating: false,
          pinned: true,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  )),
              background: Image.network(
                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
        ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid this is the standard behavior of the FlexibleSpaceBar. You can change the color but not make it transparent.

A workaround I found is to use a Stack instead of the FlexibleSpaceBar:

```
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 200.0,
  floating: true,
  pinned: true,
  snap: true,
  flexibleSpace: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Image.network(
          "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              "Collapsing Toolbar",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24.0,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Hello Thierry and thank you for your time. Yes, it is pretty close but if the Text or another image is too long it will spread on the back arrow at the top. How to limit the Length of the text "Collapsing Toolbar" or image?

Comment: Not sure I understand. What back arrow are we talking about? Can you provide a screenshot? Do you want to limit the length of the text in characters? Or adapt the font size?

Comment: After the welcome page I have a button that routes it to another page with the sliverappbar we are talking about and by default it generates a back arrow to pop the existing route. But if I have a long text or image it goes behind that back arrow that pops the route.